# (How) can I use Jinja2's sandbox mode in python-docx-template (docxtpl)?

Tags: python, jinja2, python-docx, docxtpl

I would like to use docxtpl for an app that lets users autopopulate Word documents from their own Word templates. The user would be able to enter any code they want into the jinja2 fields/tags in their templates. That raises a security concern about executing user submitted code.

Jinja2 has its `SandboxedEnvironment` for evaluating untrusted code, which prohibits access to unsafe methods and attributes. Docxtpl uses jinja2. But I don't see anything in the docxtpl documentation about using the sandbox mode.

Is this possible? How?

Reference: Jinja2 sandbox docs: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/sandbox/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's what I came up with to answer my question.

**Q:** Is this possible? **Answer:** yes.

**Q:** How? **Answer:** By passing `SandboxedEnvironment` into the render method of `DocxTemplate` as the optional paramater `jinja_env`.

Here's a working example:

*docx_sandboxed.py*

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from jinja2.sandbox import SandboxedEnvironment


class aClass():

    def safe_method(self):
        return "THIS IS safe_method"

    def __str__(self):
        return "This should raise a SecurityError exception"

doc = DocxTemplate("input_danger.docx")
A = aClass()
context = {
    'var1': 'VAR1',
    'object': A,
}

doc.render(context, jinja_env=SandboxedEnvironment())
doc.save("output.docx")
```

*input_danger.docx*

```
{{ var1 }}
{{ object.__str__() }}
```

Running the code with *input_danger.docx* as shown above raises `jinja2.exceptions.SecurityError: access to attribute '__str__' of 'aClass' object is unsafe.`

Change the second field to `{{ object.safe_method() }}` and it works, producing:

*output.docx*

---

VAR1

THIS IS safe_method

---

I'd be glad to hear of any issues/concerns that may arise with this approach.